# Laravel Forge - "killed" - npm verb exit 137 - dying on Laravel Mix

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-mix, laravel-forge

I recently updated the versions of Node and NPM on my server on Forge from Node v14.19.0 to v18.17.1 and NPM v.6.14.16 to v9.6.7. I have also updated my dependencies. Not sure if this is relevant, but I needed to change Forge's password on the server.

When deploying, `npm install` runs fine but when I run `npm run dev`, I always get the response "Killed" from Forge. Specifically "npm verb exit 137", which indicates that I have run out of memory.

Here is the output:

```
> dev
> mix

QUEUE_CONNECTION set to "redis", make sure to start a queue worker.

● Mix █████████████████████████ emitting (98%)
 after emit

Outbound Data: File generated!
Ziggy Routes: Files generated!
Killed
```

I have tried to fix this by adding the max-old-space-size to my script:

```
"dev": "NODE_OPTIONS=\"--max-old-space-size=8000\" mix "
```

However, this hasn't helped and the I keep getting the same error.

I have also tried to run `npm run prod` and am getting the same error.

I have also tried getting into the server via SSH and running `npm run dev` and `npm run prod`. Unfortunately, this doesn't give me any further information.

I have also tried running `npm cache clean --force` and then running `npm run dev`, but am having the same issue.

Any idea what could be happening here and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of server are you running things on? Is it a tiny AWS `t3.nano` or something?

Comment: How much ram do you have on the server?

Comment: hey guys, I'm running on a t3.small server on AWS with 2 GiB of memory. Maybe I should also note that I can run `npm run dev` on my local machine with no issues. So, there's nothing there that stops it. It could be just a small machine size. I'll try to increase it to t3.medium. Note that the CPU utilization only gets up to 62% with the t3.small.

Comment: It says Out of memory, so 2G would not be enough. It may be enough if it was all used for that script, but remember that the OS and other services also use up memory, so you may only have 1-1.5G free, if you're lucky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, the reason for the error was that the server was too small (despite working perfectly fine before). What fixed it was upgrading from a t3.small (2GB memory) to a t3.medium (4GB memory).